# CSS overlapping error

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` called big box that contains another `<div>` called small box. Each small box contains an image and text wrapped inside a separate `<div>` I also have a diagram to explain my situation.

http://s21.postimg.org/4thwzlt9j/Untitled.jpg

The problem is when the text is larger than the div wrapping it. If I create another small box, It will overlap the above small box.

How can I modify the CSS so if the elements such as the text go over the `<div>` the small box won't overlap it.

http://s18.postimg.org/kqkqlp6w9/Untitled.png

I don't want to use margin because it is fixed. What happens if one small box has only 3 words of text and there's a huge margin at the bottom?

How can I make it dynamically, so if the text is bit over, the second small box won't overlap it but will instead adjust it's size so it will be at the bottom with space?

```
  .bigbox {height: 700px;  
  width: 950px; 
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#D5DADA;
  border-width:1px;}

 .smallbox {text-align:center;
  height:300px;
  width:250px;
  background: #FFB236;
  position:relative;
  left:0px;top:0px;
  margin-bottom: px;}

 .imagebox img{margin:6px 6px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="bigbox">
<div class="smallbox"><div class="i"><img border="0"src="im.jpg" alt="">  </div>This is the text and it is wrapped inside a div.  </div>
<div class="smallbox"><div class="imagebox"><img border="0"src="im.jpg" alt="">  </div>This is the text and it is wrapped inside a div.</div>
```

Comment: @CL75 Thank for the edit . It's make this question much more cleaner

Comment: No problem, backticks were missing from the references to your `<div>` tags in the opening paragraph so it threw me off :) But in the future just add those backticks and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply removing the `height` attribute of the `.smallbox` worked for me.
The problem with specifying a fixed height is that it simply does not allow the `div` to expand such that all the content fits inside.

If there is more content than what the `div` can hold, it *overflows*. The overflow can be visible or hidden depending on how you specify it, but it *does not change the layout* and *does not act as content*.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtBUd/